# jQuery send value of hidden field on click event

Tags: jquery, buttonclick

I am using the following template to display data from the database. It is repeated and identical classes are used several times.  I want to pass the value of the hidden field that is in that template on the `onclick` event of `btnDelete`.

```
<div class="Template">
    <div class="Title"></div>
    <div class="Price"></div>
    <div class="_Qty">Total Tickets:<div class="TotalQty"></div></div>
    <div class="_Qty1">Sold Tickets:<div class="UsedQty"></div></div>
    <div class="_Date">On Sale:<div class="StartDate"></div></div>
    <div class="_Date1">Sale Ends:<div class="EndDate"></div></div>
    <input type="hidden" value="8c991c10-7d88-4212-b931-5bfeff4ebcd0" />
    <input type="button" class="btnDelete" value="Remove Ticket" onclick="fnRemoveTicket(**THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO PASS HID VALUE**);"/>
    <input type="button" class="btnEdit" value="Edit Ticket"/>
</div>
```

I don't know how to pass the value of the hidden field that is in the same parent as the button.   Normally, I would select the button with some type of unique selector. Then do something like `$(this).closest`  or `$(this).parent`. Since I have nothing unique about the button, I have to pass it inline with the `onclick` event, but I don't know how to get this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `prev` or `siblings` method.

```
$('.btnDelete').click(function(){
     var val = $(this).prev().val();
     // var val = $(this).siblings("input[type='hidden']").val()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

```
$('input.btnDelete').on('click', function(){
    var hidden = $(this).parent().find('input[type="hidden"]');
    /* actions */
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this is close - but I have more then one type of button on my  page  so I would have to use .where() in the one , where the other answer does the same with class selector

Comment: You will use the right selector instead of `$('input[type="button"]')`. My code is just an example of "how to do".

Comment: I know , I got it , i was just commenting that yours works fine - just other answer was almost the same at almost the same time , but his was a little bit bit closer, so I have to accept his

Answer (score 0):

You can use `siblings()` method to find the nearby element stay in the same parent. 
ie:

```
 $('input.btnDelete').click(function(){
   var $hiddenVal = $(this).siblings('input[type="hidden"]').val();
   fnRemoveTicket($hiddenVal);
});
```

Here is the workable demo on: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zVGNW/)